# D3 Multiple Instances of wForceSimulation

Tags: d3.js

Hope someone can help with my first D3 visualisation. I've got two datasets that I've loaded in as separate selections of group elements. I'm trying to simulate forces on the bubbles however I can only get one of the groups to function at once. I have a feeling it's something to do with calling d3.forceSimulation multiple times but I can't figure out a workaround. Any help appreciated! (Apologies for sloppy coding, not been in the game long! Github repo: https://github.com/skemp456/D3)

[Visualisation (middle group (features) doesn't work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6UcS.png)

```
function createBubbleChart(error, features, dummydata) {
  var features_f = features.map(function(d) { return d.Feature});
  var features_t = d3.set(dummydata.map(function(tech) { return tech.Feature; }));
  var importance = {'Tertiary':30,'Secondary':45,'Critical':60},
      //importanceExtent = d3.extent(importance.values),
      importanceScaleX,
      importanceScaleY;
  var categories = d3.set(features.map(function(d) { return d.Category}));
  var catColourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(categories.values())
      .range(["#1092E1", "#E13610", "#11B40C"])
  var featureColourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
        .domain(features.values());
  var columns = d3.set(['Technology - Networks',
                    'Technology - Apps & Devices and Security & Privacy',
                    'Internal to the Community',
                    'Legislation, Standards, Economic, Political, Social']);
  var timeScales = d3.set(['Now', 'Now - 6 months', '6 Months - 1 Year', '1 Year - 3 Years', '3 Years +'])
  var impact = dummydata.map(function(tech) { return tech.Impact; }),
      impactExtent = d3.extent(impact),
      impactScaleX,
      impactScaleY;


  var width = 1200,
      height = 800;

  var svg,
      circles,
      f_circles,
      t_circles,
      circleSize = {min: 30, max:60},
      clusterPadding = 6

  var circleRadiusScale_t = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain(impactExtent)
    .range([circleSize.min, circleSize.max]);

  var circleRadiusScale_f = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain(importance)
    .range([circleSize.min, circleSize.max])

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("z-index", "10")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("max-width", "300px")
      .style("color", "white")
      .style("padding", "8px")
      .style("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)")
      .style("border-radius", "6px")
      .style("font", "12px sans-serif")
      .text("tooltip");

  var forces,
      forceSimulation,
      forceSimulation2;

  //Call functions here
  createSVG();
  createFCircles();
  createTCircles();
  createForces();
  createForceSimulation();
  addGroupingListeners();




  /////////////////////////////////
  //---------Functions-----------//
  /////////////////////////////////
  //Function to create the simple vector graphic space
  function createSVG() {
    svg = d3.select("#bubble-chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("class", "bubble");
  }
  //Function to determine if a html element is checked
  function isChecked(elementID) {
    return d3.select(elementID).property("checked");
  }
  //Create feature circles
  function createFCircles() {
    f_circles = svg.selectAll("f_circle")
      .data(features)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "f_circle")

    f_circles
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return importance[d.Importance]; })
      .style("fill", function(d) {return catColourScale(d.Category);})
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeElastic)
          .duration("500")
          .attr("r",  importance[d.Importance]+20);
        d3.select("#clipCircle"+i+" circle").transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", importance[d.Importance]+10);
        d3.select("#text"+i).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("200")
          .attr("y", 12)
          .attr("font-size", 32)
          .attr("fill", "#333");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeQuad)
          .delay("10")
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", importance[d.Importance]);
        d3.select("#clipCircle"+i+" circle").transition()
          .ease(d3.easeQuad)
          .delay("10")
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", 0);
        d3.select("#text"+i).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("400")
          .delay("10")
          .attr("y", 7)
          .attr("font-size", 20)
          .attr("fill", "#FFF");
      });

    f_circles.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .text(function(d){ return d.Feature; });
  }
  //Create Technology Circles
  function createTCircles() {
    t_circles = svg.selectAll("t_circle")
      .data(dummydata)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "t_circle")

    t_circles
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cursor", "pointer")
      .attr("r", function(d) {return circleRadiusScale_t(d.Impact); })
      .style("fill",  function(d) {return featureColourScale(d.Feature);})
      .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeElastic)
          .duration("500")
          .attr("r",  function(d) {return circleRadiusScale_t(d.Impact)+10; });
        d3.select("#clipCircle"+i+" circle").transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", function(d) {return circleRadiusScale_t(10); });
        d3.select("#text"+i).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("200")
          .attr("y", 12)
          .attr("font-size", 32)
          .attr("fill", "#333");
        tooltip.text(d.Description);
        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })
      .on("mousemove", function() {
        return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeQuad)
          .delay("10")
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", function(d) {return circleRadiusScale_t(d.Impact); });
        d3.select("#clipCircle"+i+" circle").transition()
          .ease(d3.easeQuad)
          .delay("10")
          .duration("200")
          .attr("r", 0);
        d3.select("#text"+i).transition()
          .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
          .duration("400")
          .delay("10")
          .attr("y", 7)
          .attr("font-size", 20)
          .attr("fill", "#FFF");
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      });

    t_circles.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .text(function(d){ return d.Technology; });

  }

  function createForces() {
    var forceStrength = 0.15;
    forces = {
      features: createFeaturesForces(),
      cases: createCasesForces(),
      timeScales: createTimeScalesForces()
    };

    function createFeaturesForces() {
      return {
        x: d3.forceX(featureForceX).strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY(featureForceY).strength(forceStrength)
      };
      function featureForceX(d) {
        if ("Importance" in d) {
          return (width /2);
        }else{
          return (width + 1000);
        }
      }

      function featureForceY(d) {
        if ("Importance" in d) {
          return (height /2);
        }else{
          return (height /2);
        }
      }
    }
    function createCasesForces() {
      return {
        x: d3.forceX(casesForceX).strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY(casesForceY).strength(forceStrength)
      };
      function casesForceX(d) {
        if ("Technology" in d) {
          return (width /2);
        }else{
          return (width-1000);
        }
      }

      function casesForceY(d) {
        if ("Technology" in d) {
          return (height /2);
        }else{
          return (height / 2);
        }
      }
    }
    function createTimeScalesForces() {
      var columnNamesDomain = columns.values();
      var timeScalesDomain = timeScales.values();
      var scaledTimeMargin = circleSize.max;

      timeScaleX = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(columnNamesDomain)
        .range([scaledTimeMargin, width - scaledTimeMargin*2]);
      timeScaleY = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(timeScalesDomain)
      .range([height - scaledTimeMargin, scaledTimeMargin*2]);

      var centerCirclesInScaleBandOffset = timeScaleX.bandwidth() / 2;
      return {
        x: d3.forceX(function(d) {
          if ("Technology" in d){
            return timeScaleX(d.Column) + centerCirclesInScaleBandOffset;
          }else{
            return (0 - width/2);
          }

        }).strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY(function(d) {
          if("Technology" in d){
            return timeScaleY(d.Timescale);
          }else{
            return (0 - height/2);
          }
        }).strength(forceStrength)
      };
    }
  }
  function createForceSimulation() {
    //Create forces for cases
    forceSimulation_t = d3.forceSimulation();
    forceSimulation_t
      .force("x", forces.features.x)
      .force("y", forces.features.y)
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide));
    forceSimulation_t
      .nodes(dummydata)
      .on("tick", function() {
        t_circles
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
      });

    //Create forces for features
    forceSimulation_f = d3.forceSimulation();
    forceSimulation_f
      .force("x", forces.features.x)
      .force("y", forces.features.y)
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide));
    forceSimulation_f
      .nodes(features)
      .on("tick", function() {
        f_circles
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
      });
  }

  function forceCollide(d) {
    if ("Technology" in d){
      return circleRadiusScale_t(d.Impact)+2;
    }else{
      return importance[d.Importance]+2;
    }
  }

  function featureGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Features");
  }

  function casesGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Cases")
  }

  function timeScaleGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Time-Scales");
  }

  function addGroupingListeners() {
    addListener("#Features", forces.features);
    addListener("#Cases", forces.cases);
    addListener("#Time-Scales", forces.timeScales);

    function addListener(selector, forces) {
      d3.select(selector).on("click", function() {
        updateForces_t(forces);
        updateForces_f(forces);
        toggleTimeScaleAxis(timeScaleGrouping());
        //toggleFeaturesKey();
      });
    }

    function updateForces_t(forces) {
      forceSimulation_t
        .force("x", forces.x)
        .force("y", forces.y)
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide))
        .alphaTarget(0.5)
        .restart();
    }

    function updateForces_f() {
      forceSimulation_f
        .force("x", forces.x)
        .force("y", forces.y)
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide))
        .alphaTarget(0.5)
        .restart();
    }
    function toggleTimeScaleAxis(showAxes) {
      var onScreenXOffset = 100,
          offScreenXOffset = -40;
      var onScreenYOffset = 120,
          offScreenYOffset = 100;

      if (d3.select(".x-axis").empty()) {
        createAxes();
      }
      var xAxis = d3.select(".x-axis"),
          yAxis = d3.select(".y-axis");

      if (showAxes) {
        translateAxis(xAxis, "translate(20," + (height - onScreenYOffset) + ")");
        translateAxis(yAxis, "translate(" + onScreenXOffset + ",-50)");
      } else {
        translateAxis(xAxis, "translate(0," + (height + offScreenYOffset) + ")");
        translateAxis(yAxis, "translate(" + offScreenXOffset + ",0)");
      }

    function createAxes() {
      var numberOfTicks = 10,
          tickFormat = ".0s";

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(timeScaleX)
        .ticks(numberOfTicks, tickFormat);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + offScreenYOffset) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll(".tick text")
          .attr("font-size", "16px");

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(timeScaleY)
        .ticks(numberOfTicks, tickFormat);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + offScreenXOffset + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
    }

    function translateAxis(axis, translation) {
      axis
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .attr("transform", translation);
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: my run results that ALL circles are in the origin. Why do you have a center force when you also have X and Y force? The only nodes of the forcesim are the dummy circles and you only update the Case-circles in the force tick

Comment: your simulation never ends because you set `alphaTarget` use `alpha`

Comment: what do want to happen when the `Feature` or the `Cases` option is selected? what should happen with the nodes of the other group? Should both groups be visible in the `Time-Scale` option?

Comment: Only one group of nodes should be visible at a time. The features nodes should only be there on the 'Features' option and then slide off screen when another option is selected. The 'Cases' nodes should slide on screen when 'Cases' option is selected or 'Time-Scale'

Comment: `f_circle` and `t_circle` are non existing SVG elements a select will always be empty. Where is `#clipCircleXXX`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must update the transform of the enclosing `g` in the force tick not the `cx` and `cy`.

```
    t_circles
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;})
      // .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
      // .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;});
```

You must also add the features objects to the force simulation, now only the Case nodes are animated and updated.

Set a new `alpha` value to start the force again, otherwise the sim will never end.

```
function updateForces(forces) {
  forceSimulation
    .force("x", forces.x)
    .force("y", forces.y)
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide))
    // .alphaTarget(0.5)
    .alpha(0.5)
    .restart();
}
```

**Edit**

The root cause of the immobile nodes is the fact that you are not allowed to share forces between simulations. Reason: a force keeps track of the nodes used in the simulation. You are allowed to share the accessor functions.

Also the position is changed for some cases.

```
  function createForces() {
    var forceStrength = 0.15;
    forces = {
      features: createFeaturesForces(),
      cases: createCasesForces(),
      timeScales: createTimeScalesForces()
    };

    function createFeaturesForces() {
      return {
        x: d3.forceX(featurePositionX).strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY(featurePositionY).strength(forceStrength),
        xpos: featurePositionX,
        ypos: featurePositionY
      };
      function featurePositionX(d) {
        if ("Importance" in d) {
          return (width /2);
        }
        return (width + 1000);
      }

      function featurePositionY(d) {
        if ("Importance" in d) {
          return (height /2);
        }
        return (height /2);
      }
    }
    function createCasesForces() {
      return {
        x: d3.forceX(casesPositionX).strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY(casesPositionY).strength(forceStrength),
        xpos: casesPositionX,
        ypos: casesPositionY
      };
      function casesPositionX(d) {
        if ("Technology" in d) {
          return (width /2);
        }
        return (0 - 1000);
      }

      function casesPositionY(d) {
        if ("Technology" in d) {
          return (height /2);
        }
        return (height / 2);
      }
    }
    function createTimeScalesForces() {
      var columnNamesDomain = columns.values();
      var timeScalesDomain = timeScales.values();
      var scaledTimeMargin = circleSize.max;

      timeScaleX = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(columnNamesDomain)
        .range([scaledTimeMargin, width - scaledTimeMargin*2]);
      timeScaleY = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(timeScalesDomain)
      .range([height - scaledTimeMargin, scaledTimeMargin*2]);

      var centerCirclesInScaleBandOffset = timeScaleX.bandwidth() / 2;
      return {
        x: d3.forceX().strength(forceStrength),
        y: d3.forceY().strength(forceStrength),
        xpos: timePositionX,
        ypos: timePositionY
      };
      function timePositionX(d) {
        if ("Technology" in d){
          return timeScaleX(d.Column) + centerCirclesInScaleBandOffset;
        }
        return (0 - width/2);
      }
      function timePositionY(d) {
        if("Technology" in d){
          return timeScaleY(d.Timescale);
        }
        return height/2;
      }
    }
  }
  function createForceSimulation() {
    //Create forces for cases
    forceSimulation_t = d3.forceSimulation();
    forceSimulation_t
      .force("x", forces.cases.x)
      .force("y", forces.cases.y)
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide));
    forceSimulation_t
      .nodes(dummydata)
      .on("tick", function() {
        t_circles
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
      });
    // we use the wrong position functions so update
    updateForces(forceSimulation_t, forces.features);

    //Create forces for features
    forceSimulation_f = d3.forceSimulation();
    forceSimulation_f
      .force("x", forces.features.x)
      .force("y", forces.features.y)
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(forceCollide));
    forceSimulation_f
      .nodes(features)
      .on("tick", function() {
        f_circles
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
      });
  }

  function forceCollide(d) {
    if ("Technology" in d){
      return circleRadiusScale_t(d.Impact)+2;
    }else{
      return importance[d.Importance]+2;
    }
  }

  function featureGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Features");
  }

  function casesGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Cases")
  }

  function timeScaleGrouping() {
    return isChecked("#Time-Scales");
  }

  function updateForces(forceSim, forces) {
    forceSim.force("x").x(forces.xpos);
    forceSim.force("y").y(forces.ypos);
    forceSim.alpha(0.5).restart();
  }
  function addGroupingListeners() {
    addListener("#Features", forces.features);
    addListener("#Cases", forces.cases);
    addListener("#Time-Scales", forces.timeScales);

    function addListener(selector, forces) {
      d3.select(selector).on("click", function() {
        updateForces(forceSimulation_t, forces);
        updateForces(forceSimulation_f, forces);
        toggleTimeScaleAxis(timeScaleGrouping());
        //toggleFeaturesKey();
      });
    }
    function toggleTimeScaleAxis(showAxes) {
      var onScreenXOffset = 100,
          offScreenXOffset = -40;
      var onScreenYOffset = 120,
          offScreenYOffset = 100;

      if (d3.select(".x-axis").empty()) {
        createAxes();
      }
      var xAxis = d3.select(".x-axis"),
          yAxis = d3.select(".y-axis");

      if (showAxes) {
        translateAxis(xAxis, "translate(20," + (height - onScreenYOffset) + ")");
        translateAxis(yAxis, "translate(" + onScreenXOffset + ",-50)");
      } else {
        translateAxis(xAxis, "translate(0," + (height + offScreenYOffset) + ")");
        translateAxis(yAxis, "translate(" + offScreenXOffset + ",0)");
      }

      function createAxes() {
        var numberOfTicks = 10,
            tickFormat = ".0s";

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(timeScaleX)
          .ticks(numberOfTicks, tickFormat);

        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x-axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + offScreenYOffset) + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll(".tick text")
            .attr("font-size", "16px");

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(timeScaleY)
          .ticks(numberOfTicks, tickFormat);
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y-axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + offScreenXOffset + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);
      }

      function translateAxis(axis, translation) {
        axis
          .transition()
          .duration(100)
          .attr("transform", translation);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks rioV8, I've updated those things in the GitHub repo however I still only get one set of nodes responding. The other just doesn't move after it's initial force placement to the center.

Comment: @SamKemp : What do you want in all three cases (3 radio buttons)?